# How to shorten file urls

Tags: 8, uri

So for a file the standard url is `example.com/sites/default/files/the_file.pdf` how can I get rid of the leading `/sites/default` ?

Comment: You can add Apache rewrite rule, shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Also you can switch to the private fiel system where the path would be /system/ instead of /sites/default/files

Comment: Thanks. The problem with a rewrite would be that the urls created by drupal would stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of the **/sites/default/files/** part and change it to something shorter then just go to the **admin menu** and follow **Configuration > Media > File System**

( Or just follow the url : **/admin/config/media/file-system** )

There set your **Public file system path** and **Private file system path** to what ever you want.

**---- EDIT ----**
Actually the above is valid for **Drupal 7**.
For **Drupal 8** you will have to change the value of ***$settings['file_public_path']*** in the settings.php file, [as mentioned by 4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/178219/6902).
In D8 the Configuration > Media > File System page displays these two parameters but no longer allows editing them.
**----END EDIT----**

So you could change your **sites/default/files** to something like **resources** for example.

And then your files will have   urls like this : **example.com/resources/the_file.pdf**
instead of what you had : **example.com/sites/default/files/the_file.pdf**

Also **make sure that** :
  - your resources directory exists, and
  - is located at your web document root directory, and
  - is writable by your apache user (or whatever webserver you use).

Of course, this will be fine for a fresh setup, but if you already have a lot of contributed stuff then changing these settings may impact on your existing node contents.

Answer (score 1):

ShURLy is no option, it is not avaiblable for drupal 8.

To change the location of the file, use settings.php:

```
$settings['file_public_path']  = 'path/to/the/files/directory';
```

If you want to keep the file in the same location and only change the url of the file you can put a rewrite into .htaccess.